# Removing a NSString path strings

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsstring

I have a NSString which looks like `/test/test1/test2`. How could I delete the `test2`, knowing that it can be named in any other way? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking for NSString's [`stringByDeletingLastPathComponent`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByDeletingLastPathComponent) method (documentation linked for you).

Comment: exactly what I was looking, I'll accept in 9 minutes, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The NSString method [`- (NSString *)stringByDeletingLastPathComponent`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByDeletingLastPathComponent) will do what you want.

One note though, it will turn "/foo/bar/" into "/foo/" which may or may not be desirable.